# new to server hosting, what do i need to know? should I?

Tags: hosting, datacenter, dedicated-server, virtual-hosting

I am planning (mostly hoping) to create and manage my own server for some python web apps, Apache/PHP/MySQL as well as a minecraft server. I have never hosted anything more complicated than a mediawiki on LAMP, and a minecraft server, so there is my experience with hosting. I have also been using Linux (using ubuntu since 8.04) as my only OS for a while, so I know my way around bash, ssh, screen, and such.

now what I want/hope: to build my own server and find a server rack to place it in a datacenter,

so question one is: where can I find a good comparison of datacenters? with a preference that I can drive to it for any on-site maintenance.

question two: about how much would it cost for rack space and 100mb internet? I have tried looking, but alas, I know not enough to compare what I see.

what about a virtual server? will those be powerful enough to run a minecraft server along with some other things? will I even be allowed to?

specs im looking at making/using:

- 24GB ram (upper end) 4 GB minimum
- dual core processor (intel AMD, whatever, it will be enough. I have been running on a tortured pentium 4 so far...)
- 50GB HDD minimum, although more the better.

Comment: Its impossible to answer this when you're not giving us any indication on traffic/load

Comment: how about a terribly small load? just a couple hundred a day tops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- where can I find a good comparison of datacenters?

You can not.

- with a preference that I can drive to it for any on-site maintenance.

Depending on where you live that will cut it down to possibly 1-2 centers anyway.

- question two: about how much would it cost for rack space and 100mb internet?

A lot. The 100mbit are the problem when quality connected. You dont need that.

- what about a virtual server? will those be powerful enough to run a minecraft server along with some other things? will I even be allowed to?

Depends. Totally. On the provider. I know powerfull virtual servers (8 cores, 32gb ram).

Comment: for some reason, i think i was a bit vague...

Comment: what speed for the uplink do you think i need? (that 100mb was some terrible math with my low amount of knowledge)

Comment: Theres no way to guess your uplink, We need to know amount of users, what your hosting(how big is it), and are you doing anything like CDN for the web stuff before we could really even guess your needs. You really should consult a professional to answer these questions for you

Comment: ah, well thanks for trying to help. i will now look up some one to call ;)

Comment: Basically it is not the speed, it is how you pay. I have 100mbit + 10mbit on my cluster (2 physical ports, 10mbit used for an admin access), paying about 30 USD per month for the ports.... and thn habe a 1000gb budget. 100mbit FLAT in a good datacenter means the hoster assumes you use it, most of the time, to 50% or more.